# How to make CUPS show a USB printer as disabled when it is disconnected?

Tags: udev, cups, printer

I'm using CUPS on an ARM single-board computer to share a USB printer over the network. To conserve power, the printer is usually powered off via a remote-controlled power outlet and only switched on via a web-interface when it is needed. When it is powered up, the printer takes about half a minute to initialize and become ready to accept print jobs.

CUPS shows the printer as "Idle" and "Ready" even when it is powered off or still initializing, but `lsusb` doesn't show the printer while it is still in an unavailable state.
I wanted a way to tell if the printer was powered on and initialized before sending it print jobs (that might hang or get dropped if the printer was unavailable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out CUPS offers the commands `cupsreject` and `cupsaccept` to mark/unmark a printer as unusable (so it will appear greyed out in print dialogs). `cupsreject` also accepts an optional `-r` parameter with a string that gives a reason for the printer's unavailability.

Combined with two `udev` rules that are executed when the printer is connected to the USB port (or powered on) and disconnected (powered off), this allows us to mark the printer as "disconnected" and have that status show up on all computers that access the printer via the network:

`/etc/udev/rules.d/usb-printer.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="03f0", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0917", RUN+="/usr/sbin/cupsaccept HP_LaserJet_3330"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="03f0", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0917", RUN+="/usr/sbin/cupsreject -r 'udev: Printer not connected' HP_LaserJet_3330"
```

Some notes for anyone who wants to adapt this solution for their own system:

- The "usb-printer" part of the rule filename is arbitrary, but `udev` might ignore it if the filename doesn't end with `.rules`.
- The USB vendor and product IDs (`0x03f0` and `0x0917` in this case) have to be changed to the IDs of your printer, as shown by `lsusb`.
- The printer name given to the `cupsaccept` and `cupsreject` commands has to match the name used by CUPS. You can list installed printers with `lpstat -v`.

Comment: note, after having applied the rules above, the printer is still in the list of cups printers and shown in printer dialogues of applications despite being unavailable